# Would SLS Block 1B's payload capacity increase if it used 4 srbs instead of 2?If so,how much?

Tags: rockets

The SLS block 1b could carry 105 tons into LEO.If it used four boosters instead of 2, how much would its payload capacity to Leo and moon increase?

Comment: SLS uses 2 solid rocket boosters. It is not a straightforward matter to double the number of boosters on a rocket. The forces would probably destroy the vehicle during launch unless it was considerably modified. For example Some parts would need to be strengthened and careful consideration would be required to adjust the thrust through Qmax the point of maximum dynamic stress with a different aerodynamic profile and a lot more thrust

Comment: Alternatively, if you just scaled the payload up to keep max Q the same, you'd need to greatly increase the thrust of the core so it could keep going after the boosters stage off, plus reinforce it to hold that payload and withstand that thrust. The core would then burn its propellant faster and not get as far, so you'd need to make it bigger, and you also need a much bigger and stronger second stage to get the payload to orbit. At this point, only the boosters really resemble the original SLS.

Comment: it'd be kind of a big move, but "why are some rockets more suited for varying numbers of boosters than others" seems like an organic outgrowth of this question and its comments which ends up more inherently interesting